# Get random text with MySQL with button click and no refresh

Tags: php, mysql, text, random

I want to get a random added text from my database. To get a new random text, I do not refresh the page but I want to be able to click a forward button.

I Anyone know how I can solve it?

There are three different things on the same page that i want to randomise.

If anyone has a different solution to this than PHP & MySQL you are welcome to share.

Comment: Question I read here `Anyone know how I can solve it?` define it

Comment: Would advise that if you are looking to get assistance, that you provide information as to what you have tried already and what is not working as expected within those attempts.

Comment: @user2061481 A bit, now you can add the things you tried. We can help you with problems in your code, we are not writing code for you. Keywords that may be helpfull, `jQuery`, `Ajax`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some difficulty expressing your problem here, but the title suggests me you need some kind of client random number generation, don't you?

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Random Number between 1 and 100" onclick="alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);" />
```

EDIT:
Ok you edited your request, now it's clear you want it from your database, it wasn't before! You should really explain HOW you generate the number, and what you're looking for is probably an AJAX request, just a guess.